# Constraint equation for wedge block system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, velocity

[image]

**Q)** What is the constraint equation of motion between wedge A and block B relative to A?

**My Approach** :
If we displace the wedge A by $x$ distance then the block B should have a net displacement of

$$x(\text{due to 1st string connected directly to wedge})+x(\text{middle string})+ x\cos\theta(\text{due to string attached to block B})$$

So total displacement $y$ of B is
$$Y = 2x + x\cos\theta$$
Differentiating we get,
$$V(B) = 2V(A) + V(A) \cos\theta$$

**Doubt** : However the correct answer to the question is $V(B) = 2V(A)$, which constradicts my approch. And I am not able to understand why there wont be any angular dependence.

**Additional**:

1. Even I checked for the extreme value of $\theta = 0⁰$
   And found the answer to be
   $V(B) = 2V(A) + V(A) \cos 0⁰$
   $V(B) = 3V(A)$
2. The virtual workdone Tension method also supports my answer.

[image]

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the incline, A, moves to the right a distance, x, then the length of string between the incline and the left side pulley, must increase by, x, and the length between the two pulleys must also increase by,x.  These two lengths must come from the string between block, B, and the right side pulley. The block moves up the incline a distance of, 2x. The speed of the block (up the incline) is twice the speed of the incline. The speed of the block relative to the horizontal surface is v + 2v cos(θ).

Answer (score 1):

If the wedge move a distance $m$ in the $\hat i$ direction then the top two bits of the string are lengthened by a total of $+m+m=2m$ which in turn means that the bottom part of the string is shortened by $2m$.
So the block moves a distance $2m$ relative to the slope.

[image]

So the distance, speed or the magnitude of the acceleration of the block, $B$, relative to the slope, $A$, is twice that of the slope, $A$, relative to the ground, $G$.
For example, $|\vec a_{\rm B,A}|=2\,|\vec a_{\rm A,G}| = 2a$ where $\vec a_{\rm B,A}$ is the acceleration of the block $B$ relative to the slope $A$, etc.

To find the acceleration of block $B$ relative to the ground $\vec v_{\rm B,G}$ use $\vec a_{\rm B,A} + \vec a_{\rm A,G} = \vec a_{\rm B,G}$.

Comment: i understand this approach but can you please elaborate why virtual work method doesn't work here as an additional $$Tcos(theta)$$ is introduced when we try that.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As in the figure, when the wedge A moves to the right by an amount 'x', then the length of the strings 1 & 2 increase by an amount 'x' as the pulley on the left is fixed. However, since the length of the string does not change, the block B moves in the direction shown by an amount '2x'. However, assuming that the block does not lose contact with the wedge, the block also moves to the right by an amount 'x' with the wedge.

So the displacement of the block B in vector is:-$$\vec{s_B}=2x\hat{a}+x\hat{b}$$
where $\hat{a}$ & $\hat{b}$ are the unit vectors along the dirction making an angle $\theta$ with the horizontal as shown and the horizontal direction respectively while the displacement of the wedge A in vector is:-$$\vec{s_A}=x\hat{b}$$
So, the displacement of block B relative to wedge A is:$$\vec{s_{B/A}}=\vec{s_B}-\vec{s_A}=2x\hat{a}+x\hat{b}-x\hat{b}=2x\hat{a}$$. Considering only magnitude, we can have:- $$s_{B/A}=2x$$ Differentiating both sides, we have:-$$V_{B/A}=2V_A$$ which is the required answer.

Note:- Question asks constraint equation of motion between wedge A and block B **RELATIVE TO A** which you are missing in your approach. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Relative velocity of B wrt A= Velocity of B wrt ground - velocity of A wrt ground
Relative velocity of B wrt A = $(\dot{x}_B\hat{i}+\dot{y}_B\hat{j})-\dot{x}_1\hat{i}$
Relative velocity of B wrt A = $(\dot{x}_B-\dot{x}_1)\hat{i}+\dot{y}_B\hat{j}$
In magnitude relative velocity of B = $\sqrt{(\dot{x}_B-\dot{x}_1)^2+(\dot{y})^2}$
$\implies (v_B)_{rel}=\sqrt{(2\dot{x}_1\cos\theta)^2+(2\dot{x}_1\sin\theta)^2}$
So, $(v_B)_{rel}=2\dot{x}_1$
Hence, $(v_B)_{rel}=2v_A$

**Using virtual work method**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Total change in the length of string=0 as string is inextensible and incompressible. In the picture $\dot{y}_B=-2\dot{x}_1\sin\theta$,  have written $\dot{y}_1$ instead of $\dot{y}_B$ in the picture.

Comment: I can get it quantitatively. But can you please give an idea why Virtual( tension )workdone method fails here as well as why we shouldnt consider the term xcosθ when we use displacement method.

Comment: See the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the following figure as below:

[image]

The length of string  given by
$$(x_2+L)\times 2+\frac{L-(x_1-x_2)}{\cos\theta}=\text{constant}$$

Differentiating above
$$2\dot{x_2}-\frac{\dot{x_1}-\dot{x}_2}{\cos\theta}=0$$

$$2\dot{x}_2-\dot{x}_1+\dot{x_2}=0$$
$$(2\cos\theta+1)\dot{x}_2=\dot{x}_1$$
or
$$\boxed{(2\cos\theta +1)V_A=V_B}$$

That's it!

Your textbook answer is incorrect!

Answer (score 0):

Lets look first at this example:
[image]

to obtain the equation of motion you have to write the components of the position vectors  relative to inertial system thus:

$$\vec R_1=\left[ \begin {array}{c} x_{{10}}\\ y_{{10}}+w_{{1}
}\end {array} \right]\\
\vec R_2=\left[ \begin {array}{c} x_{{20}}+w_{{2}}\sin \left( \theta \right) 
\\ y_{{20}}+w_{{2}}\cos \left( \theta \right) 
\end {array} \right] 
$$

where $~x_{i0}~,y_{i0}~$ are constant components .
because you have just one generalize coordinate you need one constraint equation which is:
$$w_1+w_2=l\tag 1$$

l is the constant string length

you can now obtain from equation (1)  $~w_2=l-w_1~$ and with the kinetic and potential energy you get the equation of motion

$$\ddot w_1={\frac {g \left( M-m\cos \left( \theta \right)  \right) }{M+m}}$$

so for $~\theta=0~$ you obtain the result that you can find in the internet, thus this is correct.

your case

[image]

analog the position vectors are :

$$R_1=\left[ \begin {array}{c} x_{{10}}+{\it w_1}\\ y_{{10
}}\end {array} \right] \\
R_2=\left[ \begin {array}{c} x_{{20}}+w_{{2}}\sin \left( \theta \right) 
\\ y_{{20}}+w_{{2}}\cos \left( \theta \right) 
\end {array} \right] 
$$

the constraint equation

$$w_1+w_2=l\tag 1$$

and the equation of motion

$$\ddot w_1=-\frac{m\,g\,\cos(\theta)}{M+m}$$

which is also correct